# SEO in image's path?

Tags: html, seo

Does including keywords in the image's *folder* path of any importance at all for SEO ? (Keywords for the image's *filename* are important.)

/**foobar**/images/keyword.jpg

vs

/**keyword**/images/keyword.jpg

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, yes, putting short concise keywords in your image url helps, but you've got the most important part which is naming the image file as a keyword.